# How should I store per request data when using OWIN to Self-Host ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm in the process of converting my ASP.NET Web API from being IIS hosted to being self hosted.

In one of my `DelegatingHandlers` I set the current user based on the token from the HTTP header. I've been using `HttpContext.Current.Items` to store this information, but that isn't available under self hosting.

What is the correct way to store per request data that can be accessed anywhere in my application?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this? I'm stuck using an IoC container whose PerWebRequest method is using the HttoContext.Current

Comment: Check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28242568/879655.

Answer (score 0):

The Request message has a Properties collection.

Comment: But the `Request` isn't available everywhere is it?

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad. It is not static.  However, it is available throughout the request/response pipeline.  Static properties are major challenge when using a free-threaded framework like web API.