# Data caching per request in Owin application

Tags: asp.net, owin

In traditional ASP.NET applications (that use System.Web), I'm able to cache data in

```
HttpContext.Current.Items
```

Now in Owin the HttpContext is not available anymore. Is there a way to do the similar thing in Owin - a **static** method/property through which I can set/get **per request data**?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368130/should-i-use-owincontexts-environment-to-hold-application-specific-data-per-req?rq=1) gave some hints but not exact a solution in my case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally I found [OwinRequestScopeContext](https://github.com/neuecc/OwinRequestScopeContext). Very simple to use.

In the Startup class:

```
app.UseRequestScopeContext();
```

Then I can add per request cache like this:

```
OwinRequestScopeContext.Current.Items["myclient"] = new Client();
```

Then anywhere in my code I can do (just like HttpContext.Current):

```
var currentClient = OwinRequestScopeContext.Current.Items["myclient"] as Client;
```

[Here](https://github.com/neuecc/OwinRequestScopeContext/blob/master/Source/OwinRequestScopeContext/OwinRequestScopeContext.cs) is the source code if you're curious. It uses CallContext.LogicalGetData and LogicalSetData. Does any one see any problem with this approach of caching request data?

Comment: I up-voted this answer because; it is a new approach I was unaware of.  I've always used [DalSoft](http://stackoverflow.com/users/324497/dalsoft)'s approach.  Does anyone know the difference between the two?  This approach seems more **global** while DalSoft's seems a bit more **local**, but I'm still not certain of the difference.

Comment: OwinRequestScopeContext.Current is null always. Please help.

Comment: In startup.cs, call app.UseRequestScopeContext() before you enable WebApi - or put it at the very top.

Answer (score 15):

You just need to use [OwinContext](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/owincontext-and-why-you-can-have-many-of-them/) for this:

**From your middleware:**

```
public class HelloWorldMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
   public HelloWorldMiddleware (OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }

   public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
   {   
       context.Set("Hello", "World");
       await Next.Invoke(context);     
   }   
}
```

**From MVC or WebApi:**

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Get<string>("Hello");
```